# Get data from one table using id and date ranges stored in another table

Tags: sql

The app I am writing is for telemetry units that get rented out to customers, and I am trying to query logged data for a particular customer, without a `customer_id_fk` column in the `Log` table.

I have the following tables:

Customer table:

```
id | name | ...
```

Unit table:

```
id | name | ...
```

RentOut table:

```
id | start_date | end_date | unit_id_fk | customer_id_fk
```

Log table:

```
id | unit_id_fk | datetime | data1 | data2
```

The reason a `customer_id_fk` column is not included in the `Log` table is so that a mistake in the RentOut table is easily rectified, without the need to alter data in the `Log` table (though maybe there is a better way to do this?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more efficient to include the customer in the log table.  But, without that, you can get what you want with a bunch of joins:

```
select l.*, c.*
from log l left outer join
     RentOut ro
     on l.unit_id_fk = ro.unit_id_rk and
        l.datetime between ro.start_date and ro.end_date left outer join
     Customer c
     on ro.customer_id = c.id
where c.<whatever> = <foobar>
```

If the dates in the RentOut table are really dates (with no times), and the log records have a datetime, then you might have to do more date arithmetic for the join to work properly.  For instance, you might need to say the "start" really is after noon and the "end" is really before noon, for a given log record.

Comment: I predict to have around 3 million rows in the log table each year, do you think the above query would be a bad idea? Probably the performance impact has more to do with the amount of rows in the RentOut table?

Comment: @Flo . . . That is a fair amount of data.  Be sure you have indexes set up on `RentOut(unit_id_fk, start_date, end_date)` and on the primary keys on all tables.  That should help the performance.